# How to achieve an arch appBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement this kind of `AppBar` in Flutter, any advice on how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: That will have something to do with clipping. https://medium.com/flutter-community/clipping-in-flutter-e9eaa6b1721a

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Material(
      elevation: 12,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(500, 70), bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(500, 70)),
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Text("dride", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white)),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[800], borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(500, 70), bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(500, 70))),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I was looking for a solution that will keep the native AppBar in place, I saw in the docs the 'bottom' property, I'm working on a way to get that to work.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible keeping native `AppBar` but once you figured it out, please post your answer. Thanks :)